# Erro ao converter números. Como converter fatores para números?

Tags: r, data.frame, factors

No seguinte exemplo:

```
dados <- data.frame(x=c("11", "10", "20", "15"), y=c("25", "30", "35", "40"))
dados
   x  y
1 11 25
2 10 30
3 20 35
4 15 40
```

Ao tentar transformar a variável `x` em número, ao invés de 11, 10, 20 15 aparecem:

```
as.numeric(dados$x)
[1] 2 1 4 3
```

Como converter `x` para números?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se você analisar a estrutura do objeto verá onde ocorre o problema:

```
str(unclass(dados$x))
atomic [1:4] 2 1 4 3
- attr(*, "levels")= chr [1:4] "10" "11" "15" "20"
```

O objeto `dados$x` é composto do vetor [2,1,4,3] com o atributo `levels`. Esse atributo que aparece no console quando é feito o print de `dados$x`.

Para resolver o problema, além da solução já mencionada, você pode adotar a seguinte solução:

```
as.numeric(levels(dados$x))[dados$x]
```

Na primeira parte da solução são extraídos e convertidos em número os atributos do objeto `dados$x`. O `R` automaticamente coloca esses valores em ordem crescente. Então você usa  `[dados$x]` para deixá-los na ordem original.

Essa solução é ligeiramente mais eficiente do que `as.numeric(as.character(dados$x))`, entretanto pode ser mais difícil de lembrar.

Answer (score 10):

No `R`, o comportamento padrão do `data.frame` é transformar textos em fatores. Isso pode gerar resultados inesperados quando números, durante o processo de importação/manipulação de dados, são erroneamente interpretados como textos e transformados em fatores.

Em geral, ao trabalhar com `data.frames`, é interessante colocar a opção `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` para evitar que variáveis que não devem ser tratadas como fatores o sejam.

Entretanto, uma vez que a variável tenha sido indevidamente transformada em fator, uma solução possível é convertê-la em `character` primeiro antes de passar para número:

```
as.numeric(as.character(dados$x))
[1] 11 10 20 15
```