# Data.frame para ts dados diários no R

Tags: r

Não estou conseguindo transformar a cotação diária do câmbio para ts.

```
dados <- read.table("C:/Econometria/Cambio/cambio.txt", header=T, dec=",")
ts(dados), start=c(1994,01,01), freq=1) # Quando faço isso ele muda os dados, acaba aparecendo valores que não estão no arquivo
```

Também usei `xts(dados, as.Date(dados, format='%m/%d/%Y')`

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
str(dados)
'data.frame':   5103 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ X1: Factor w/ 4142 levels "-","0,829","0,831",..: 86 81 70 65 74 77 74 74 77 83 ...

dput(dados)
... , "3,9245", "3,9552"), class = "factor")), .Names = "X1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5103L))
```

Comment: Diogo, coloque o resultado de `str(dados)` e se possível `dput(dados)` na sua pergunta, para sabermos o que tem na sua base de dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diogo, o problema é que os seus valores não estão como número, e sim como `factor` (fatores).

Isso está ocorrendo na hora de ler a base de dados porque o `R` está interpretando o seu dado como texto (e não como número) e transformando em `factor`.

Se você observar a informação que você deu com o `str`, o primeiro level é um traço "-". Provavelmente é isso o que está causando o problema. Sugiro você substituir esses valores por zero antes de proceder novamente à leitura.

PS: Por curiosidade, se você quiser entender porque fatores transformados em números viram "outros" números, sugiro ler essa pergunta: [Erro ao converter números. Como converter fatores para números?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9284/erro-ao-converter-n%C3%BAmeros-como-converter-fatores-para-n%C3%BAmeros) .

Comment: Uma outra alternativa poderia ser substituir os valores "faltantes" por `NA` usando o argumento `na.strings` da função `read.table`. No seu caso, seria `read.table(..., na.strings='-')`