# Como transformar dados importados do Excel (.csv) em séries temporais

Tags: r, csv, séries-temporais

Importei um banco de dados do Excel para R e preciso transformá-los em séries temporais para poder analisá-los. Entretanto, quando vou fazer a transformação para séries temporais o R altera os valores originais para outros totalmente diferentes. Abaixo os passos que utilizei

para importar os dados:

```
variavel=read.table("dados.csv", header=T, sep=";", dec=",")
```

após importação dos dados, os valores apareceram da forma correta na variável atribuída, sendo valores do tipo 5.547,18...

para transformar os dados em séries temporais:

```
library(tseries)# carregando o pacote séries temporais

ts.variavel=ts(variavel, start=c(2000,1), frequency=12) # fazendo a transformação
```

após a transformação acima, quando vou consultar os dados eles aparecem totalmente alterados, por exemplo, o valor de 5.547,18 virou 15, o valor 5.344,47 virou 7, o valor 5.053,42 virou 2 e por aí vai... Estranho, não?! O que será que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: A resposta do Daniel parece plausível mas, caso não resolva seu problema, você poderia postar um exemplo dos seus dados? Por exemplo: `dput(head(variavel))`.

Comment: Obrigado por ajudar, consegui resolver o problema conforme resposta do Daniel.

Comment: Vale a pena dar uma olhada nessa pergunta também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9284/erro-ao-converter-n%C3%BAmeros-como-converter-fatores-para-n%C3%BAmeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o problema é a leitura dos dados.

Aparentemente seus dados possuem um separador de milhares que o R não está entendendo. Por isso ele lê as variáves como `factor`, que depois é transformado em um inteiro.

A forma mais fácil de resolver este problema é: no próprio excel formatar as colunas para não ter o separador de milhares.

Verifique que os dados estão sendo lidos corretamente com:

```
str(variavel)
```

Essa função deve indicar que os seus dados são do tipo numérico e não do tipo factor. Exemplo:

```
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ x: num  0.426 0.664 0.844 0.76 0.781 ...
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado.