# Como arredondar valores de um data.frame no R usando o operador %>% do dplyr?

Tags: r

tenho um data.frame com muitos valores com mais de 2 casas após a vírgula, eu gostaria de arredondar para apenas 2 casas após a virgula usando de preferência o operador `%>%`, se possível, pois esta operação é muito comum no meu estudo e não gostaria de gerar data.frames intermediários.

Seja este pedaço do meu data.frame com a coluna `IQA`

```
a<-read.table(text = "Estacao2  IQA Ano Ano2    Epoca
1   58.5    2005    2005-01-01  Chuvoso
1   61.5    2005    2005-01-01  Seca
10  73.5    2005    2005-01-01  Chuvoso
10  74.577  2005    2005-01-01  Seca
11  68.577  2005    2005-01-01  Chuvoso
11  69  2005    2005-01-01  Seca
12  69.566  2005    2005-01-01  Chuvoso
14  75.25   2005    2005-01-01  Seca
15  52.33333333 2005    2005-01-01  Chuvoso
15  65  2005    2005-01-01  Seca
16  77.37577    2005    2005-01-01  Chuvoso
16  76.375  2005    2005-01-01  Seca
17  52.28571429 2005    2005-01-01  Chuvoso
17  54.22   2005    2005-01-01  Seca
", sep="", header = TRUE)

a
```

Update:
substitui as virgulas por pontos, nao tinha percebido isso antes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com `dplyr` e `stringr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

a %>% 
  mutate(.data = ., across(.cols = IQA, .fns = ~ str_replace_all(string = ., pattern = ",", replacement = "."))) %>% 
  mutate(.data = ., across(.cols = IQA, .fns = ~ as.numeric(.))) %>% 
  mutate(.data = ., across(.cols = IQA, .fns = ~ round(x = ., digits = 2)))

#   Estacao2     IQA  Ano       Ano2   Epoca
#1         1   58.50 2005 2005-01-01 Chuvoso
#2         1   61.50 2005 2005-01-01    Seca
#3        10   73.50 2005 2005-01-01 Chuvoso
#4        10   74.58 2005 2005-01-01    Seca
#5        11   68.58 2005 2005-01-01 Chuvoso
#6        11   69.00 2005 2005-01-01    Seca
#7        12   69.57 2005 2005-01-01 Chuvoso
#8        14   75.25 2005 2005-01-01    Seca
#9        15   52.33 2005 2005-01-01 Chuvoso
#10       15   65.00 2005 2005-01-01    Seca
#11       16   77.38 2005 2005-01-01 Chuvoso
#12       16   76.38 2005 2005-01-01    Seca
#13       17   52.29 2005 2005-01-01 Chuvoso
#14       17 5422.00 2005 2005-01-01    Seca
```

Ou elimine a seguinte linha:

```
mutate(.data = ., across(.cols = IQA, .fns = ~ str_replace_all(string = ., pattern = ",", replacement = ".")))
```

e coloque `dec = ","` dentro da função `read.table`. Agora pode fazer assim:

```
a %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = IQA, .fns = ~ round(x = as.numeric(.), 2)))
```

Comment: Note que a conversão de `character` é mais simples quando comparada aquela feita com `factor`. Veja essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9284/erro-ao-converter-n%c3%bameros-como-converter-fatores-para-n%c3%bameros) para não se confundir quando isso ocorrer.

Comment: `mutate(across(.cols = IQA, .fns = ~ round(x = as.numeric(.), 2)))` é execlente