# Erro na conversao de character em numeric no R

Tags: r, conversão

Uma das questões da minha base de dados se refere ao tamanho da propriedade rural dos indivíduos `(Base22$`106`)`.
Estou tentando converter as respostas da referida questão para `numeric` ou `double`, mas sem sucesso.
Embora a classificação da variável que criei seja numérica, não consigo, por exemplo, calcular a média ou utilizar a função `summarise` (tal como disposto no código a seguir).

```r
dput(head(Base22$'106', 20))
c("99", "99", "25", "99", "99", "99", "10", "99", "99", "99", 
"8", "20", "1", "40", "22", "99", "2", "17", "99", "2")
```

```
class(Base22$`106`)
[1] "character"
Base22$PosseTerra<-as.numeric(Base22$`106`)
class(Base22$PosseTerra)
[1] "numeric"
```

```r
dput(head(Base22$PosseTerra, 20))
c(99, 99, 25, 99, 99, 99, 10, 99, 99, 99, 8, 20, 1, 40, 22, 99, 
2, 17, 99, 2)
summarise(Base22$PosseTerra)
```

```
Error in UseMethod("summarise") : 
  no applicable method for 'summarise' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

Answer (score 4):

Suponha que seu banco de dados tenha o nome `df_1` e que sua variável tenha o nome `x`:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(x = c("99", "99", "25", "99", "99", "99", "10", "99", "99", "99", 
"8", "20", "1", "40", "22", "99", "2", "17", "99", "2"))
```

Você precisa converter este vetor da seguinte forma:

```
df_1$y <- as.numeric(as.character(df_1$x))
```

*Usei `df_1$y` para não sobrescrever `x`.*

Creio que você esteja usando `dplyr` por conta da forma que contou seu problema. Então, agora faça:

```
library(dplyr)

df_1 %>% 
  summarise(somei = sum(y))

#  somei
#1  1137
```

Usei a função `sum`, mas você pode usar uma diversidade delas que são aplicáveis em vetores `numeric` e `double`, como `var()` e `sd()`.

***Missings***

Caso tenha *missings* (`NA`), deve-se aplicar o parâmetro `TRUE` no argumento `na.rm`, pois por *default* o parâmetro é `FALSE`. Este padrão fará com que o retorno seja `NA` sempre que existam *missings* no vetor. Então

```
df_1 %>% 
  summarise(somei = sum(y, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Recomendo dar uma olhada nesta pergunta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9284/108927), ajudará um pouco no entendimento de conversões de números em `R`.

Comment: Obrigada pelo retorno. Fiz o que sugeriu, mas o resultado da soma é um "NA". `Base22$PosseTerra<-as.numeric(as.character(Base22$`106`))` `Base22 %>% 
  summarise(somei = sum(PosseTerra))` `somei 1    NA`

Comment: Editei a pergunta, veja agora se resolveu.

Comment: Deu certo! Usei a função `coalesce` para substituir `NA`'s. Muito obrigada